# asking for a Ph.D thesis

Tags: support

Is it right to request certain document of academic nature such as Ph.D thesis in forums?

At present, I need a Ph.D thesis for some references.

Comment: Just curious why this -1. I was told that meta is the place where you can ask questions about the site and this is what I did.

Comment: Voting on Meta works differently than on the main site: upvotes indicate agreement, downvotes indicate disagreement with the statement contained in the post. So in this instance I would read this vote as "no, SciComp is in general not a forum to request PhD theses" (and would agree). That said, it could be acceptable if it's a thesis likely to be of relevance to others in scientific computing (say, of historical interest like Young's thesis) and hard to obtain (i.e., if the venues Paul mentioned have failed -- make sure to mention that in the question).

Answer (score 5):

If you need a specific person's PhD thesis, kindly ask them directly for it by email or request a copy via your local library's resources.  The Stack Exchange is intended to be a repository for general Q & A, not for uploading dissertations/theses.

Comment: It is pretty much a requirement that Ph.D theses are treated as publications, with copies retained at the awarding institution's library in the usual case.  If this route (interlibrary loan and an appeal to the author) did not work, it might be worth describing the particular case at Academia.SE to get more specific advice.